# Python library to do what the UNIX command 'dialog' does

Tags: python

I need text-console interactive dialogs. I am porting a shell script to Python. Which Python tool would do pretty much exactly what the UNIX command `dialog` does? (i.e. ready-to-use yes/no, calendar, text, gauge, etc. controls which return results and are ncurses-like full-screen UIs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/).

Urwid provides a higher-level toolkit on top of curses and includes an event loop to handle keyboard and mouse input. It either uses it's own select-based event loop, or can hook into gevent or Twisted.

In addition to handling keyboard input efficiently you'll also have a host of options to handle user input with edit boxes, list controls and more.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html). It's low-level, but has the advantage of being a part of the standard library.

Answer (score -1):

These are dialog Python bindings: http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/